# Multivariate function with bounded derivatives implies Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, dynamical-systems

Assume we have a differentiable function: $$f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}\\f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$$

If: $$\|\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial x}\|\leq M_i,\|\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial y}\|\leq N_i,\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$$
for some positive constants $M_i,N_i$, $i=1,2$, can I then conclude that $f(x,y)$ is $Lipschitz$ continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}$ ?

I know that the above holds for funcitons $\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but I couldn't find anything related to functions $\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}.$

Context: Im trying to show the uniqueness of solution for a system: $$\underline{x}'(t)=f(\underline{x}(t)) $$
and the result follows immediately if I can show that $f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz.

If a similar post has been made before I'd appricate the link to it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: why not just apply the 1D result to each $f_i$?

Comment: @ZachHunsucker in my case my f is continuously differentiable. So I can make the jump from the bounded derivatives and say that my f is lipschitz?

Comment: @CalvinKhor oh, like show that both $f_i$ are Lipschitz and from that conclude that f is Lipschitz too?

Comment: yes. I'm not sure what zach is referring to tho

Comment: @CalvinKhor perfect, thank you for the help